# Remove Quantity Increment Button Based on Attribute

Tags: magento-1.9

On the product page, I want to remove the Incremental Quantity option buttons if a given attribute in that product is "Yes". In this case product attribute "ddq_enabled" must be set to "Yes" for the Incremental Quantity option not to be desired.

I'm new to php so I do not know what syntax to use but I pretty much want to create an if statement

If ddq_enabled is yes, then only show the add to cart button.

If ddq_enabled is no, then we can default to the regular view

Below is my phtml file - I'm sure this is an easy one. Thank you...

```
 <?php

?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="add-to-cart">
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
        <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
        <div class="qty-button"> 

                <div class="box-icon button-minus">
                    <input type="button" onclick="var qty_el = document.getElementById('qty'); var qty = qty_el.value; if( !isNaN( qty ) &amp;&amp; qty &gt; 0 ) qty_el.value--;return false;" class="qty-decrease" />
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
                <div class="box-icon button-plus"> 
                    <input type="button" onclick="var qty_el = document.getElementById('qty'); var qty = qty_el.value; if( !isNaN( qty )) qty_el.value++;return false;" class="qty-increase " />
                </div>  


        </div>      
        <?php endif; ?> 
        <button type="button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"> <span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></button>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Did one of the answers helped you get the job done?

Answer (score 0):

First get the value of your attribute:

```
<?php $ddqenabled = $_product->getDdqEnabled(); ?>
```

Surround the piece of code that should be shown if ddq_enabled is "no" with an if statement:

```
<?php if($ddqenabled == 0) : ?>
  *** Your piece of code ***
<?php endif; ?>
```

If Ddq is enabled the attribute will return a "1" and your increment section will be skipped.

Basically your code could look like this:

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php $ddqenabled = $_product->getDdqEnabled(); ?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<div class="add-to-cart">
    <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped() && ($ddqenabled == 0)): ?>
    <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
    <div class="qty-button"> 

            <div class="box-icon button-minus">
                <input type="button" onclick="var qty_el = document.getElementById('qty'); var qty = qty_el.value; if( !isNaN( qty ) &amp;&amp; qty &gt; 0 ) qty_el.value--;return false;" class="qty-decrease" />
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
            <div class="box-icon button-plus"> 
                <input type="button" onclick="var qty_el = document.getElementById('qty'); var qty = qty_el.value; if( !isNaN( qty )) qty_el.value++;return false;" class="qty-increase " />
            </div>  


    </div>      
    <?php endif; ?> 
    <button type="button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"> <span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></button>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

This Logic

```
<?php 

     if($_product->getAttributeText('ddqenabled')=='Yes')
    {
      <!-- Your display code -->
    }
    else {
            <!-- your else part code -->
           }
     ?>
```

Your try this

```
<?php

?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="add-to-cart">
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
        <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>

        <?php if($_product->getAttributeText('ddqenabled')=='Yes'){?>
        <div class="qty-button"> 

                <div class="box-icon button-minus">
                    <input type="button" onclick="var qty_el = document.getElementById('qty'); var qty = qty_el.value; if( !isNaN( qty ) &amp;&amp; qty &gt; 0 ) qty_el.value--;return false;" class="qty-decrease" />
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
                <div class="box-icon button-plus"> 
                    <input type="button" onclick="var qty_el = document.getElementById('qty'); var qty = qty_el.value; if( !isNaN( qty )) qty_el.value++;return false;" class="qty-increase " />
                </div>  
<?php }

 else {?>
<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />

<?php }?>


        </div>      
        <?php endif; ?> 
        <button type="button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"> <span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></button>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```